# SqlSrv driver isn't loading with IIS 10 & PHP 5.6

Tags: iis, php-5.6, sqlsrv

I've installed a fresh IIS 10 server on a fresh Windows 10 machine with [PHP 5.6.31](https://secure.php.net/downloads.php#v5.6.31) *VC11 x64 Non Thread Safe* (can't use PHP7 just yet). PHP is now working well and `phpinfo()` is displaying everything correctly.

I just installed the PHP SQL driver but it isn't being loaded. It's not showing up in `phpinfo()` and when I try to use it in code I get the following PHP error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in test.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 test.php(3): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:server=...', '', '')
```

To install the PHP SQL driver, I did the following:

- Downloaded and installed the [Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434) (x64)
- Downloaded and installed the [Microsoft Driver for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) (SQLSRV32.EXE)
- Enabled the extensions in PHP manager (`php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll`)
- Restarted the IIS server

[image: PHP extensions]

```
[PHP_XDEBUG-2.5.5-5.6-VC11-NTS-X86_64]
extension=php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-nts-x86_64.dll
[PHP_PDO_ODBC]
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_56_NTS]
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
[PHP_SQLSRV_56_NTS]
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

It all looks correct to me and I've done this successfully on other machines before. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

A few other notes:

- The PHP error log is empty.
- I've tried loading all other dll files that I downloaded (such as the ones aimed at 5.5, 5.4 etc) but it doesn't change anything.

It's worth noting that I installed Xdebug just fine and it **is** showing up in `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by using PHP for x86 and not x64. I'm guessing that the SQL drivers are not designed for x64 (although I couldn't see this anywhere).

As soon as I changed to [PHP 5.6 VC11 x86 Non Thread Safe](http://windows.php.net/download) everything worked much better.

Note that you need [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/EN-US/DOWNLOAD/DETAILS.ASPX?ID=30679) x86 for this to work. If you already installed the x64 redistributable you will need to install the version that is designed for x86.

Comment: SQL Server drivers for PHP 7 supports x64.

Comment: PHP 5.6 is known to have multiple issues with x64. If you do need 64 bit support, you should consider 7.x.

Answer (score -2):

or use this library : php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll

Comment: Why would installing version 7.3 fix an issue in 5.6?